# Set Variable Name to Length of Array

Tags: python

Is it possible to set the name of variable to the length of an array in Python?

For example (in pseudo-code):

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
someVar[len(list)] = obj(value1, value 2)
```

So the variable could be referred to like:

```
print (someVar3)
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: A dict would suffice.

Comment: You could also do it as an attribute of an object, e.g. `setattr(theObject,str(len(list)),obj(val1,val2))`. However, this is an evil, evil abuse of `setattr`.

Comment: care to explain why you would want to do this?

Comment: @Foon Just a general query. I suppose it could be implemented into a system where the user creates several instances of an object, like a registration system. It wouldn't be terribly efficient at all, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as **@user2097159** said in his comment, you're better off using a `dict`:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
someVar = {}
someVar[len(my_list)] = obj(value1, value 2)
print (someVar[3])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
someVar = {}
obj= [4,5]
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
someVar[len(my_list)] = (obj[0], obj[1])

print someVar[3]
```

output:

```
(4, 5)
```

Yes, just use a dict.

Also, don't use 'list' as a variable name. It's already a `built-in type`

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you suggest only if the element already exists (when using a list). But using a dictionnary is a better option here :

```
d = {}
d[any_hashable_object] = object
```